# Compilation/Linking to Cairo Library

Tags: gcc, compilation, include, cairo

I am trying to test out a few simple Cairo programs, but I am having trouble figuring how to include the source files.  I have installed the Cairo library - it's just a question of how to let gcc know...

- I have the .h files (including cairo.h) installed in /usr/local/include/cairo
- I have the .dylib files installed in /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/lib/cairo

Are there any other components of the installation I should be aware of? (I just did 'make install' to install the library)

I am trying to compile like this:

```
$ gcc cairoTest.c -I/usr/local/include/cairo -L/usr/local/lib/
```

My cairoTest.c file starts out with:

```
include <cairo.h>
```

gcc is finding cairo.h, but it gives the following error message.  I think it is not linking to the .dylib files correctly, but I'm not sure.  I'm still new to compiling/linking.

```
gcc cairoTest.c -I/usr/local/include/cairo -L/usr/local/lib/cairo
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cairo_image_surface_create", referenced from:
      _main in ccVd9Pet.o
  "_cairo_create", referenced from:
      _main in ccVd9Pet.o
  "_cairo_scale", referenced from:
      _main in ccVd9Pet.o
  "_cairo_set_line_width", referenced from:
      _main in ccVd9Pet.o
  "_cairo_set_source_rgb", referenced from:
      _main in ccVd9Pet.o
  "_cairo_rectangle", referenced from:
      _main in ccVd9Pet.o
  "_cairo_stroke", referenced from:
      _main in ccVd9Pet.o
  "_cairo_surface_write_to_png", referenced from:
      _main in ccVd9Pet.o
  "_cairo_destroy", referenced from:
      _main in ccVd9Pet.o
  "_cairo_surface_destroy", referenced from:
      _main in ccVd9Pet.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

What should I be doing differently to include the Cairo library in my compilation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9):

Try to compile with

```
 gcc -Wall -g cairoTest.c -I/usr/local/include/cairo -L/usr/local/lib/ -lcairo -o cairoTest
```

(but you probably need other libraries, perhaps thru `$(pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo)` or similar)

And your file should start with

```
 #include  <cairo.h>
```

Comment: Thanks! A friend of mine actually explained pkg-config to me.  That helped, so I figured out the right flags, and I'm compiling successfully now. Also, I forgot the # in my question, but I had it in my file.

I tried to give your comment an "up", but it said I need a higher reputation.

Comment: -lcairo was what I was missing